# C# Kurdish Language Localization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

How can I support Kurdish language at my wpf project?
I create resources files for different cultures **(Localization)**

```
French  ->  fr 
English ->  en
Arabic  ->  ar
.
.
.

Kurdish ->  ???
```

And if windows dose not support this language, How can i use **CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder** class to add this culture? 
And is there any another way?

Answer (score 4):

ku-Arab

All supported codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx)

Comment: I have message 
**Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
ku-Arab is an invalid culture identifier**

When I write `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ku-Arab")`

Comment: @AmjadSham: Try `ku` first, perhaps. Also the list of supported cultures may change depending on how old your OS is. On my Windows 10 I have `ku` (Central Kurdish), `ku-Arab` (Central Kurdish (Arabic)), `ku-Arab-IQ` (Central Kurdish (Iraq)), and `ku-Arab-IR` (Kurdish (Perso-Arabic, Iran)). Now, trying the same on an ancient Windows version will likely be missing some of those.

Comment: The link to the supported list refers to the Bing Maps REST API. I somehow doubt the relevance for WPF ...

Answer (score 0):

**Format Date Iraq by using this class**

```
public static class DateSetting
{
    public static string ToDateIraq(DateTime date) => date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static string ToDateTimeIraq(DateTime date) => date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt");
}
```

[format date and time](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Answer (score -1):

This code show how to use **CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder** to add Kurdish localization to system culture types. Note that code registering culture in **UserCustomCulture** store. This code works only under Windows 7 or older. Under Windows 10 not working (and Windows 8 too I think). In Windows 10 there is already Kurdish culture ku-Arab.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildCulture();
    }

    public static void BuildCulture()
    {
        if(cultureExist())
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("ku-KU");
        Console.WriteLine("Create the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder...");

        var cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("ku-KU", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
        cib.CultureEnglishName = "Kurdish (Kurdistan)";
        cib.RegionEnglishName = "Kurdistan";
        cib.CultureNativeName = "ßæÑÏí";
        var cia = new CultureInfo("ar-IQ");
        cib.NumberFormat = cia.NumberFormat;
        cib.GregorianDateTimeFormat = cia.DateTimeFormat;
        cib.TextInfo = cia.TextInfo;
        cib.CompareInfo = cia.CompareInfo;
        cib.KeyboardLayoutId = cia.KeyboardLayoutId;
        cib.RegionNativeName = "ßæÑÏÓÊÇä";
        cib.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "kur";
        cib.ThreeLetterISORegionName = "kur";
        cib.TwoLetterISORegionName = "ku";
        cib.ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName = "kur";
        cib.ISOCurrencySymbol = "USD";
        cib.CurrencyNativeName = "Dinary Kurdi";
        cib.CurrencyEnglishName = "Kurdish Dinar";

        var cinull = new CultureInfo("");
        cib.Parent = cinull;
        cib.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName = "kur";
        cib.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "ku";
        cib.IetfLanguageTag = "kurdisk";
        cib.Register();
        cib.Save(@"C:\temp\kurdish.xml"); //Save created culture to XML document

        Console.WriteLine("Create and explore the custom culture...");
        var ci = new CultureInfo("ku-KU");
        Console.WriteLine("Name: . . . . . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("EnglishName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.EnglishName);
        Console.WriteLine("NativeName: . . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.NativeName);
        Console.WriteLine("TwoLetterISOLanguageName: . . . {0}", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
        Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterISOLanguageName: . . {0}", ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
        Console.WriteLine("ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName: {0}", ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName);
        Console.Read();
    }

    //Register culture from XML file
    private void cmdCreateCultureFromXML()
    {
        if(cultureExist())
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("ku-KU");

        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cib = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml(@"C:\temp\kurdish.xml");
        cib.Register();
    }

    private static bool cultureExist()
    {
        var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture);

        return cultures.Where(s => s.Name == "ku-KU").Any();
    }

}
```

Read more: [Time to Add Kurdish Culture to VS .NET
Globalization](http://proceedings.informingscience.org/InSITE2007/IISITv4p353-363Ali323.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean?